# How to open a blank workbook automatically after hidden startup workbooks are added?

Tags: excel, vba

Background: I have created an alternative startup location with two files in it on the network (one .xslb and one .xla), for the purpose of macro storage, and distribution.

Problem 1: When I open Excel from the shortcut there is no blank workbook.

Problem 1 Solution: A blank drawing opens when I open Excel from shortcut. Code Shown below added to `ThisWorkbook` Excel Object of startup file.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Workbooks.Count <= 2 Then
        Workbooks.Add
    End If
End Sub
```

Problem 2: I now open a blank drawing every time I open excel even when I double click `RandomName.xlsm`, I would like to suppress this. I understand that the code will run on the startup workbooks, condition will be true, open the blank book, and then opens `RandomName.xslm`.

Comment: What does "Open from shortcut" mean. What shortcut? Which file are you clicking on?

Comment: That would be the shortcut to excel.exe. Sorry, does sound a bit confusing.

Comment: So your problem is that when you open Excel it doesn't open a new, blank workbook? That is not default behavior and should be fixed by repairing Office, not by running some custom VBA every time you open the program...

Comment: A binary workbook (.xlsb) as well as a add-in workbook (.xla) are both still considered workbooks. So, Excel believes it is opening a workbook on startup, that is why there is no blank, or so my research tells me. This happens on any computer where I add startup documents, not a problem repairing office will help.